# javascript input not showing value but console shows it has it

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to find out why the text from the div is not being shown by the input field. the debugger console shows that the field does contain the value but still does not show it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head><title>Copy value</title></head>
        <body>
            <div id="text">text</div>
            <input type="text" id="result" />
            <script>
                var divValue = document.getElementById("text").textContent;
                console.log(divValue)
                var inputElement = document.getElementById("result");
                inputElement.Value = divValue;
                console.dir(inputElement)
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo, `Value` should be `value`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head><title>Copy value</title></head>
        <body>
            <div id="text">text</div>
            <input type="text" id="result" />
            <script>
                var divValue = document.getElementById("text").textContent;
                console.log(divValue)
                var inputElement = document.getElementById("result");
                inputElement.value = divValue;
                console.dir(inputElement)
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```